# How to fix apt-get broken updating wireshark

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, update-manager

After an update a few months ago Wireshark would not update.  I learned to un-check it but forgot today.  Updater has downloaded all the updates. I get the following error messages when I try to update.  I probably made a mistake when I tried apt-get remove and apt-get purge to get rid of Wireshark.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libwireshark-data
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libwireshark-data
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/848 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,292 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 233363 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwireshark-data_1.99.6+git20150422121542~afb70bba-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0_all.deb ...
Unpacking libwireshark-data (1.99.6+git20150422121542~afb70bba-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwireshark-data_1.99.6+git20150422121542~afb70bba-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/wireshark/dtds/pocsettings.dtd', which is also in package wireshark-common 1.99.0+git20140730111853~82bb8008-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwireshark-data_1.99.6+git20150422121542~afb70bba-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
programmer@fireimager:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwireshark0:amd64:
 libwireshark0:amd64 depends on libwireshark-data (>= 1.99.6+git20150422121542~afb70bba-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0); however:
  Package libwireshark-data is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libwireshark0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libwireshark0:amd64
```

This fails, too.

```
apt-get -f install
```

How can I fix the apt-get DB?

Edit

Based on Terrance's comment I searched again and found:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq wireshark
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreqgrep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* wireshark
```

I got the first command to run but the second appears to be malformed.

In `/usr/share/wireshark` I found these files and directories (`partial` is empty).

```
libwireshark-data_1.99.6+git20150422121542~afb70bba-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0_all.deb  
libwireshark-data_1.99.6+git20150424075214~b284de81-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0_all.deb  
lock  
partial
```

`/usr/share/wireshark` has several directories and files.

I can get along quite well without Wireshark.

EDIT

```
apt-cache policy libwireshark-data

libwireshark-data:
  Installed: 1.99.6+git20150430165916~3bf0d14a-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0
  Candidate: 1.99.6+git20150430165916~3bf0d14a-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0
  Version table:
 *** 1.99.6+git20150430165916~3bf0d14a-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dreibh/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1.10.6-1 0
    500 http://apt-cache policy wireshark-common/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

and

```
apt-cache policy wireshark-common

wireshark-common:
  Installed: 1.99.6+git20150430165916~3bf0d14a-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0
  Candidate: 1.99.6+git20150430165916~3bf0d14a-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0
  Version table:
 *** 1.99.6+git20150430165916~3bf0d14a-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dreibh/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1.10.6-1 0
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Here are some commands you can try over at this site (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=947124#9)

Comment: Can you run `sudo aptitude why wireshark` to see what programs need wireshark, and see if those can be deleted?

Comment: @ike It returns `Unable to find a reason to install wireshark.`

Comment: Can you try it for `libwireshark-data`? Something needs that to be installed, or `apt-get install -f` wouldn't try to install it.

Comment: [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/612654/edit) your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libwireshark-data` and `apt-cache policy wireshark-common`. Then give me a comment with @A.B.

Comment: @A.B. I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the following steps will not solve the problem. Both packages, `wireshark-common` and `libwireshark-data` try to create the same file. Please contact [Thomas Dreibholz](https://launchpad.net/~dreibh).

---

Let us still try.

It is possible that `aptitude` proposes different versions for conflict resolution. Look at all the proposals and choose the best. I can not foresee the problems. You are dependent on yourself.

1. Install two tools:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
   sudo apt-get install aptitude
   ```

   It is possible that in the following steps `aptitude` proposes different versions for conflict resolution. Look at all the proposals and choose the best. I can not foresee the problems. You are dependent on yourself.
2. Housekeeping:

   ```
   sudo aptitude clean
   ```
3. Remove the PPA `ppa:dreibh/ppa` temporary:

   ```
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:dreibh/ppa
   ```
4. Remove wireshark:

   ```
   sudo aptitude remove wireshark
   ```
5. Add the PPA again:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dreibh/ppa
   ```
6. Install `wireshark`

   ```
   sudo aptitude install wireshark
   ```

Comment: The commands were run without complaint and apt-get works again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

so at least one file `pocsettings.dtd` is included in both package libwireshark-data and libwireshark-common. Try to remove that file name from:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libwireshark-common.list
```

so it doesn't know about the conflict and will install the new version.

Comment: That file does not exist!

Comment: hmm, the error message implied to me that wireshark-common is already installed.

Comment: wireshark-common may have been installed before I tried to remove wireshark ...

Comment: have you tried removing libwireshark ? if not try  sudo apt-get purge libwireshark0:amd64 and then try sudo apt-get update

Comment: @Aravinda Both commands ran without error but didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this in terminal:

```
rm -fr  /var/cache/apt/archives/libwireshark-data_1.99.6+git20150422121542~afb70bba-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa0_all.deb
apt-get clean
apt-get update
dpkg --purge libwireshark-data
dpkg --purge wireshark*
apt-get install -f
```

it must help to clean your apt-get, and install new packages